# Linux System Monitor

Tags: c++, linux

I made a system monitor on Linux which gives you all this information:

[image]

The full project can be found in my repo:
https://github.com/sandro4912/System-Monitor

In short it works as following:

I read the data from various folders in the Linux file system

This Data gathering is organized in the classes:

- Memory -> reads Memory consumption from file and calculates various parts of the memory usage
- Processor -> reads Data from the CPU and its Cores. Calculates the utilization for cpu and each core
- Process -> Reads data from a process. It just needs the PID.
- Parser -> Not a class but some freestanding functions which read addition information like OS name for system

I made an abstract base class for these classes so depending of the OS (currently only Linux) the right Memory Process and Processor classes are selected at runtime.

The Class System gathers all the data from Memory Process and Processor and presents it to an output with NCurses.

I would like to present some classes here for review (all is probably too much).

Please let me know.

- What do you think about the design?
- Is the code clean, easy to read?
- What would you improve?
- Any bad habits?

Feel free to also look in the other code in the git repo and comment on them aswell.

As A side node. I know the code for NCurses is quite messy. I plan to replace it later with QT.

**system.h**

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

#include "memory.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "processor.h"

class System {
   public:
    System();

    std::string Kernel() const;
    std::string OperatingSystem() const;

    std::shared_ptr<Processor> Cpu();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> Processes();
    std::shared_ptr<Memory> MemoryUtilization();
    long UpTime() const;
    int TotalProcesses() const;
    int RunningProcesses() const;

   private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> updateProcesses();

    const std::string mKernel;
    const std::string mOperatingSystem;

    std::shared_ptr<Processor> mCpu;
    std::shared_ptr<Memory> mMemory;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> mProcesses = {};

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> mLastCpuTimePoint{};
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> mLastMemoryTimePoint{};
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> mLastProcessTimePoint{};
    static constexpr auto mMinReadDifferenceInMS = 100;
};

#endif
```

**system.cpp**

```
#include "system.h"

#include "parser.h"

#include <unistd.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

System::System()
    : mKernel{Parser::Kernel()},
      mOperatingSystem{Parser::OperatingSystem()},
      mCpu{std::move(Processor::makeProcessor())},
      mMemory{Memory::makeMemory()},
      mLastCpuTimePoint{std::chrono::system_clock::now()},
      mLastMemoryTimePoint{mLastMemoryTimePoint} {}

std::string System::Kernel() const { return mKernel; }

std::string System::OperatingSystem() const { return mOperatingSystem; }

std::shared_ptr<Processor> System::Cpu() {
    auto newTimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        newTimePoint - mLastCpuTimePoint);

    if (duration.count() > mMinReadDifferenceInMS) {
        mCpu = std::move(Processor::makeProcessor());
        mLastCpuTimePoint = newTimePoint;
    }
    return mCpu;
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> System::Processes() {
    auto newTimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        newTimePoint - mLastProcessTimePoint);

    if (duration.count() > mMinReadDifferenceInMS) {
        mProcesses = updateProcesses();
        mLastProcessTimePoint = newTimePoint;
    }

    return mProcesses;
}

// DONE: Return the system's memory utilization
std::shared_ptr<Memory> System::MemoryUtilization() {
    auto newTimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        newTimePoint - mLastMemoryTimePoint);

    if (duration.count() > mMinReadDifferenceInMS) {
        mMemory = std::move(Memory::makeMemory());
        mLastMemoryTimePoint = newTimePoint;
    }
    return mMemory;
}

// DONE: Return the number of seconds since the system started running
long System::UpTime() const { return Parser::UpTime(); }

// DONE: Return the number of processes actively running on the system
int System::RunningProcesses() const { return Parser::RunningProcesses(); }

// DONE: Return the total number of processes on the system
int System::TotalProcesses() const { return Parser::TotalProcesses(); }

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> System::updateProcesses() {
    auto pids = Parser::Pids();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> processes;

    processes.reserve(pids.size());

    for (const auto& pid : pids) {
        processes.emplace_back(std::move(Process::makeProcess(pid)));
    }

    auto comparator = [](const std::shared_ptr<Process>& a,
                         const std::shared_ptr<Process>& b) { return *b < *a; };

    std::sort(processes.begin(), processes.end(), comparator);

    return processes;
}
```

**memory.h**

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#include <memory>

class Memory {
   public:
    virtual ~Memory() = default;

    virtual double TotalUsedMemoryInPercent() const = 0;
    virtual double CachedMemoryInPercent() const = 0;
    virtual double NonCacheNonBufferMemoryInPercent() const = 0;
    virtual double BuffersInPercent() const = 0;
    virtual double SwapInPercent() const = 0;

    static std::shared_ptr<Memory> makeMemory();
};

#endif
```

**memory.cpp**

```
#include "memory"

#include "linux/memory.h"

std::shared_ptr<Memory> Memory::makeMemory() {
#ifdef __linux__
    Linux::Memory memory = Linux::Memory::createFromFile();
    return std::move(std::make_unique<Linux::Memory>(memory));
#elif _WIN32
#endif
}
```

**linux/memory.h**

```
#ifndef LINUX_MEMORY_H
#define LINUX_MEMORY_H

#include "../memory.h"

#include <iosfwd>

namespace Linux {

class Memory : public ::Memory {
   public:
    Memory() = default;
    Memory(long memTotal, long memFree, long buffers, long cached,
           long swapTotal, long swapFree, long shmem, long sReclaimable);
    ~Memory() = default;

    double TotalUsedMemoryInPercent() const override;
    double CachedMemoryInPercent() const override;
    double NonCacheNonBufferMemoryInPercent() const override;
    double BuffersInPercent() const override;
    double SwapInPercent() const override;

   private:
    long mTotalMemory = 0;
    long mSwapTotal = 0;
    long mTotalUsedMemory = 0;
    long mCachedMemory = 0;
    long mNonCacheNonBufferMemory = 0;
    long mBuffers = 0;
    long mSwap = 0;

   public:
    static Memory createFromFile();
    static Memory createFromFile(const std::string& filename);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Memory& obj);

}  // namespace Linux

#endif
```

**linux/memory.cpp**

```
#include "../linux/memory.h"

#include "../helper.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace Linux {

const std::string kProcDirectory{"/proc/"};
const std::string kMeminfoFilename{"/meminfo"};

Memory::Memory(long memTotal, long memFree, long buffers, long cached,
               long swapTotal, long swapFree, long shmem, long sReclaimable)
    : mTotalMemory{memTotal},
      mSwapTotal{swapTotal},
      mTotalUsedMemory{memTotal - memFree},
      mCachedMemory{cached + sReclaimable - shmem},
      mNonCacheNonBufferMemory{mTotalUsedMemory - (buffers + mCachedMemory)},
      mBuffers{buffers},
      mSwap{swapTotal - swapFree} {}

double Memory::TotalUsedMemoryInPercent() const {
    double percent = static_cast<double>(mTotalUsedMemory) /
                     static_cast<double>(mTotalMemory);
    return percent;
}

double Memory::NonCacheNonBufferMemoryInPercent() const {
    double percent = static_cast<double>(mNonCacheNonBufferMemory) /
                     static_cast<double>(mTotalMemory);
    return percent;
}

double Memory::BuffersInPercent() const {
    double percent =
        static_cast<double>(mBuffers) / static_cast<double>(mTotalMemory);
    return percent;
}

double Memory::CachedMemoryInPercent() const {
    double percent =
        static_cast<double>(mCachedMemory) / static_cast<double>(mTotalMemory);
    return percent;
}

double Memory::SwapInPercent() const {
    double percent =
        static_cast<double>(mSwap) / static_cast<double>(mSwapTotal);
    return percent;
}

Memory Memory::createFromFile() {
    return createFromFile(kProcDirectory + kMeminfoFilename);
}

Memory Memory::createFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
    Memory memory;
    std::ifstream ifs{filename};
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        ifs >> memory;
    }
    return memory;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Memory& obj) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto memTotalOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "MemTotal:");
    if (!memTotalOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto memFreeOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "MemFree:");
    if (!memFreeOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    std::getline(is, line);  // MemAvailable:
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto buffersOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "Buffers:");
    if (!buffersOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto cachedOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "Cached:");
    if (!cachedOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        std::getline(is, line);
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto swapTotalOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "SwapTotal:");
    if (!swapTotalOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto swapFreeOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "SwapFree:");
    if (!swapFreeOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::getline(is, line);
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto shmemOpt = Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "Shmem:");
    if (!shmemOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::getline(is, line);
    }
    std::getline(is, line);
    auto sReclaimableOpt =
        Helper::ReadValueFromLine<long>(line, "SReclaimable:");
    if (!sReclaimableOpt) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    obj = std::move(Memory{*memTotalOpt, *memFreeOpt, *buffersOpt, *cachedOpt,
                           *swapTotalOpt, *swapFreeOpt, *shmemOpt,
                           *sReclaimableOpt});

    return is;
}

}  // namespace Linux
```

**process.h**

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Process {
   public:
    virtual int Pid() const = 0;
    virtual std::string User() const = 0;
    virtual std::string Command() const = 0;
    virtual long RamInMb() const = 0;
    virtual long UpTime() const = 0;
    virtual double CpuUtilization() const = 0;
    bool operator<(const Process& a) const;

    static std::shared_ptr<Process> makeProcess(int pid);
};

#endif
```

**process.cpp**

```
#include "process.h"

#include "linux/process.h"

bool Process::operator<(const Process& a) const {
    return CpuUtilization() < a.CpuUtilization();
}

std::shared_ptr<Process> Process::makeProcess(int pid) {
#ifdef __linux__
    Linux::Process process{pid};
    return std::move(std::make_unique<Linux::Process>(process));
#elif _WIN32
#endif
}
```

**linux/process.h**

```
#ifndef LINUX_PROCESS_H
#define LINUX_PROCESS_H

#include "../process.h"

#include <string>

namespace Linux {

class Process : public ::Process {
   public:
    Process(int pid);

    int Pid() const override;
    std::string User() const override;
    std::string Command() const override;
    long RamInMb() const override;
    long UpTime() const override;
    double CpuUtilization() const override;

   private:
    double calcCpuUtilization(int pid, int upTimeProcess);

    int mPid;
    std::string mUser;
    std::string mCommand;
    long mRamInMb;
    long mUpTime;
    double mCpuUtilization;
};

long ReadActiveJiffiesFromFile(int pid);
std::string ReadCommandFromFile(int pid);
long ReadRamInKbFromFile(int pid);
std::string ReadUidFromFile(int pid);
std::string ReadUserFromFile(int pid);
long ReadUpTimeFromFile(int pid);

long ParseProcessUptimeFromLine(const std::string& line);
long ClockTicksToSecond(long clockTicks);

}  // namespace Linux

#endif
```

**linux/process.cpp**

```
#include "../linux/process.h"

#include "helper.h"
#include "parser.h"

#include <unistd.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

namespace Linux {

const std::string kProcDirectory{"/proc/"};
const std::string kStatFilename{"/stat"};
const std::string kCmdlineFilename{"/cmdline"};
const std::string kStatusFilename{"/status"};
const std::string kPasswordPath{"/etc/passwd"};

Process::Process(int pid)
    : mPid{pid},
      mUser{ReadUserFromFile(pid)},
      mCommand{ReadCommandFromFile(pid)},
      mRamInMb{ReadRamInKbFromFile(pid) / 1024},
      mUpTime{ReadUpTimeFromFile(pid)},
      mCpuUtilization{calcCpuUtilization(pid, mUpTime)} {}

int Process::Pid() const { return mPid; }

std::string Process::User() const { return mUser; }

std::string Process::Command() const { return mCommand; }

long Process::RamInMb() const { return mRamInMb; }

long Process::UpTime() const { return mUpTime; }

double Process::CpuUtilization() const { return mCpuUtilization; }

double Process::calcCpuUtilization(int pid, int upTimeProcess) {
    auto uptime = Parser::UpTime();

    long startTime = upTimeProcess;
    long elapsedTime = uptime - startTime;

    long totalTime = ClockTicksToSecond(ReadActiveJiffiesFromFile(pid));

    if (elapsedTime == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return static_cast<double>(totalTime) / static_cast<double>(elapsedTime);
}

long ReadActiveJiffiesFromFile(int pid) {
    auto line = Helper::ReadFirstLineFromFile(
        kProcDirectory + std::to_string(pid) + kStatFilename);
    if (line.empty()) {
        return {};
    }

    std::istringstream ist{line};
    std::string part;
    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    ist >> part;
    // no check value type is string
    char sign;
    ist >> sign;
    if (sign != 'S') {
        return 0;
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ist >> part;
        if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto utime = std::stol(part);

    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto stime = std::stol(part);

    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto cutime = std::stol(part);

    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto cstime = std::stol(part);

    return utime + stime + cutime + cstime;
}

std::string ReadCommandFromFile(int pid) {
    std::ifstream ifs{kProcDirectory + std::to_string(pid) + kCmdlineFilename};
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(ifs, line);
        return line;
    }
    return std::string();
}

long ReadRamInKbFromFile(int pid) {
    return Helper::ReadValueFromFile<long>(
        kProcDirectory + std::to_string(pid) + kStatusFilename, "VmSize:");
}

std::string Uid(int pid) {
    return std::to_string(Helper::ReadValueFromFile<long>(
        kProcDirectory + std::to_string(pid) + kStatusFilename, "Uid:"));
}

std::string ReadUserFromFile(int pid) {
    auto targetUid = Uid(pid);

    std::ifstream ifs{kPasswordPath};
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        std::string line;

        while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
            std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ':', ' ');
            std::istringstream ist{line};

            std::string user;
            ist >> user;
            char fill;
            ist >> fill;
            std::string uid;
            ist >> uid;
            if (uid == targetUid && fill == 'x') {
                return user;
            }
        }
    }
    return std::string{};
}

long ReadUpTimeFromFile(int pid) {
    auto line = Helper::ReadFirstLineFromFile(
        kProcDirectory + std::to_string(pid) + kStatFilename);
    if (line.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ParseProcessUptimeFromLine(line);
}

long ParseProcessUptimeFromLine(const std::string& line) {
    std::istringstream ist{line};
    std::string part;
    ist >> part;
    if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
        return 0;
    }
    ist >> part;
    // no check value type is string
    char sign;
    ist >> sign;
    if (sign != 'S') {
        return 0;
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < 19; ++i) {
        ist >> part;
        if (!Helper::IsNumber<long>(part)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return ClockTicksToSecond(std::stol(part));
}

long ClockTicksToSecond(long clockTicks) {
    return clockTicks / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
}

}  // namespace Linux
```

**processor.h**

```
#ifndef PROCESSOR_H
#define PROCESSOR_H

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Processor {
   public:
    virtual ~Processor() = default;
    virtual double Utilization() const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<double> CoreUtilizations() const = 0;
    virtual int CountOfCores() const = 0;

    static std::shared_ptr<Processor> makeProcessor();
};

#endif
```

**processor.cpp**

```
#include "processor.h"

#include "linux/processor.h"

std::shared_ptr<Processor> Processor::makeProcessor() {
#ifdef __linux__
    Linux::Processor processor = Linux::Processor::createFromFile();
    return std::move(std::make_unique<Linux::Processor>(processor));
#elif _WIN32
#endif
}
```

**linux/processor.h**

```
#ifndef LINUX_PROCESSOR_H
#define LUNIX_PROCESSOR_H

#include "../processor.h"
#include "cpu_states.h"

#include <iosfwd>
#include <optional>

namespace Linux {

class Processor : public ::Processor {
   public:
    Processor() = default;
    Processor(const CpuStates& firstCpuState, const CpuStates& secondCpuState,
              const std::vector<CpuStates>& firstCoreStates,
              const std::vector<CpuStates>& secondCoreStates);
    ~Processor() = default;

    double Utilization() const override;
    std::vector<double> CoreUtilizations() const override;
    int CountOfCores() const override;

   private:
    double calcUtilization(const CpuStates& firstState,
                           const CpuStates& secondState) const;

    CpuStates mFirstCpuState{};
    CpuStates mSecondCpuState{};
    std::vector<CpuStates> mFirstCoreStates{};
    std::vector<CpuStates> mSecondCoreStates{};

   public:
    static Processor createFromFile();
    static Processor createFromFile(const std::string& filename);

    static std::optional<std::vector<CpuStates>> readFromFile(
        const std::string& filename);
    static std::optional<CpuStates> parseCpuState(const std::string line);
};

}  // namespace Linux

#endif
```

**linux/processor.cpp**

```
#include "../linux/processor.h"

#include "cpu_states.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

namespace Linux {

const std::string kProcDirectory{"/proc/"};
const std::string kStatFilename{"/stat"};

Processor::Processor(const CpuStates& firstCpuState,
                     const CpuStates& secondCpuState,
                     const std::vector<CpuStates>& firstCoreStates,
                     const std::vector<CpuStates>& secondCoreStates)
    : mFirstCpuState{firstCpuState},
      mSecondCpuState{secondCpuState},
      mFirstCoreStates{firstCoreStates},
      mSecondCoreStates{secondCoreStates} {
    assert(firstCoreStates.size() == secondCoreStates.size());
}

double Processor::Utilization() const {
    return calcUtilization(mFirstCpuState, mSecondCpuState);
}

std::vector<double> Processor::CoreUtilizations() const {
    std::vector<double> coreUtilizations;
    coreUtilizations.reserve(mFirstCoreStates.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mFirstCoreStates.size(); ++i) {
        coreUtilizations.emplace_back(
            calcUtilization(mFirstCoreStates[i], mSecondCoreStates[i]));
    }
    return coreUtilizations;
}

int Processor::CountOfCores() const { return mFirstCoreStates.size(); }

double Processor::calcUtilization(const CpuStates& firstState,
                                  const CpuStates& secondState) const {
    double deltaTotalTime = secondState.Jiffies() - firstState.Jiffies();
    double deltaActiveTime =
        secondState.ActiveJiffies() - firstState.ActiveJiffies();
    return deltaActiveTime / deltaTotalTime;
}

Processor Processor::createFromFile() {
    return createFromFile(kProcDirectory + kStatFilename);
}

Processor Processor::createFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
    auto firstStates = readFromFile(filename);
    if (!firstStates) {
        return Processor{};
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    auto secondStates = readFromFile(filename);
    if (!secondStates) {
        return Processor{};
    }

    auto firstCpuState = firstStates->front();
    auto firstCoreStates = std::vector<CpuStates>{
        firstStates.value().begin() + 1, firstStates.value().end()};

    auto secondCpuState = secondStates->front();
    auto secondCoreStates = std::vector<CpuStates>{
        secondStates.value().begin() + 1, secondStates.value().end()};

    return Processor{firstCpuState, secondCpuState, firstCoreStates,
                     secondCoreStates};
}

std::optional<std::vector<CpuStates>> Processor::readFromFile(
    const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs{filename};
    if (!ifs.is_open()) {
        return {};
    }

    std::string line;
    // Assume there must be also the CPUState
    std::getline(ifs, line);
    auto optCpuState = parseCpuState(line);
    if (!optCpuState) {
        return {};
    }
    // Assume there must be atleast one CoreState
    std::getline(ifs, line);
    auto optCoreState = parseCpuState(line);
    if (!optCoreState) {
        return {};
    }
    // optional cores
    std::vector<CpuStates> states;
    states.emplace_back(*optCpuState);
    states.emplace_back(*optCoreState);

    while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        auto optNextCoreState = parseCpuState(line);
        if (!optNextCoreState) {
            break;
        }
        states.emplace_back(*optNextCoreState);
    }
    return {states};
}

std::optional<CpuStates> Processor::parseCpuState(const std::string line) {
    CpuStates cpuStates;
    std::istringstream ist{line};
    ist >> cpuStates;
    if (ist.fail()) {
        return {};
    }
    return {cpuStates};
}

}  // namespace Linux
```